# "az storage blob upload-batch" meaning of overwrite option

Tags: azure-blob-storage

we are using the upload-batch command to upload multiple files to the blob storage, let's say to path $storage/mypath. We are also using the overwrite=true option. But I do not understand what "blob upload operation will overwrite the existing data" from the official docs is meaning.

Looking at my example blob storage path does it mean that only existing files in $storage/mypath will be overwritten when doing the upload (and existing files that are no more uploaded/overwritten are simply kept) or is the whole folder treated as a blob and then overwrite means in fact deleting the content of $storage/mypath and then uploading all the files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looking at my example blob storage path does it mean that only existing files in $storage/mypath will be overwritten when doing the upload (and existing files that are no more uploaded/overwritten are simply kept)

Yes.

> or is the whole folder treated as a blob and then overwrite means in fact deleting the content of $storage/mypath and then uploading all the files?

No.

Folders are virtual, so the latter isn't even possible.